# Como colocar un botón por encima del teclado de Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

alguno de vosotros podría ayudarme, en como conseguir que los elementos que se encuentran en la parte inferior de la aplicación aparezcan por encima del teclado de android cuando este es visible.

adjuntare unas imágenes de muestra.

Cuando el teclado esta oculto!!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando el teclado esta visible!!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como logro este efecto!?
Les agradezco de antemano su apoyo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los elementos que quieras poner encima de teclado, puedes usar un `LinerLayout` como contenedor, así puedes poner los botones, texto en horizontal, el contenedor debe estar anclado a la parte inferior de su padre, puede ser un  `RelativeLayout`

**Ejemplo:**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    ...

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <!-- Lo que quieras que se muestre por encima del teclado-->
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Luego para que los elementos anclados a la parte inferior queden por encima del teclado se debe establecer `adjustResize` así el teclado ajustará los elementos.

En `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity 
    ...
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    ...
>
```